# how can i fix 0 arguments, but got 1 problem when using the redux toolkit create actions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i've been trying to implement a redux store using redux toolkit in reactjs , but i've been getting this error

```
Calling this redux#ActionCreator with an argument will return a PayloadAction of type T with a payload of P

Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

this is my prject slice projectSlice.js where i create my slice , reducer and actions using the redux toolkit

```
import { createSlice , PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
export const projectSlice = createSlice({
    name : "project" ,
    initialState : {
        fullProject : {
            selectedProject : null,
            documents : null ,
            collaborators : null ,
            meetings : null ,
            remarks : null ,
            observations : null,
            projectSelected : null,

        }
    
    },
    reducers : {
        addProject : (state , action  ) => {

            state.fullProject.selectedProject = action.payload

        },
        selectFirstProject : (state , action  ) => {

            state.fullProject.projectSelected = action.payload

        }
    }
})


export const {  selectFirstProject } = projectSlice.actions;
export const { addProject } = projectSlice.actions;
export const selectFullProject = (state) => state.project.fullProject;


export default projectSlice.reducer;
```

and this is how i dispatch the action to redux inside a promise function

```
 function  promise   ()  {

        // SEND REQUEST TO ADD PROJECT
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/projectUpdate` , {
          'id' : project_id ,
          'projectName' : formValues.projectName ,
          'constructionType' : formValues.constructionType ,
          'addresse' : formValues.addresse ,
          'description' : formValues.description ,
          'image_url' : formValues.image_url
        }).then ( result => {

          console.log(result.data.project)
          const temp = result.data.project;
          useDispatch(addProject(temp))
             
        }
        ).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        } )
      
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a TS type for the `action` argument in either case reducer.  So, by default, RTK's TS types assume that the generated action creator takes *no* arguments.

You need to do something like `(state, action: PayloadAction<SomeTypeHere>)` instead:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-slice-state-and-action-types